# Protected pages checking user logged in doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got this

```
GET /login 302 0.622 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.609 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.808 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.733 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.695 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.740 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.717 ms - 56
GET /login 302 1.126 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.738 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.664 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.732 ms - 56
GET /login 302 0.823 ms - 56
```

with below code:

```
router.get('*', function(req,res,next){
  if(req.user){
    return next();
  }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

basically I want to not to expose my pages when user is not logged in. But why it doesn't work?

Comment: Hit a breakpoint on if and watch the req.user value

Comment: Mean hit a breakpoit of the if (req.user), navigate the page and watch the req.user value, maybe the req.user has value ?